# Drop replica from the source | Qt Remote Objects

Tags: qt, qtremoteobjects

I have application where only one replica can communicate with source at the time but want to allow another replica to overtake the communication. For that I need a way to

- figure out if any replicas currently connected to source
- drop replica from source

I can possibly to implement that in transport/TCP layer, but thought it would be cleaner to do that withing remoteobjects itself.
If there is another way to do something similar, let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Remote Objects fully supports multiple simultaneous replicas, expecting that the source need not know nor care if anyone is listening - those details are internal.  There is no interface for the source to drop a single replica.

I'm not clear on the use-case, though.  What you are doing sounds like multiple sources, not multiple replicas.